# Solidity import Tensor Flow Libraries?

Tags: oracles, import, machine-learning

Like how we import oraclize in Solidity (as follows), is there some way to import tensorflow libraries for machine learning purpose?

import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking incorrectly about what you should be doing in Solidity (that is, on the Ethereum VM.) Solidity is not a general-purpose application development language, and Dapps reference the Ethereum blockchain as a state store with minimal computation - Solidity is a language for *smart contracts*. To get a sense of what you can/should do on-chain, [play with Crypto Zombies](https://cryptozombies.io/).

While you can use the EVM for *basic* computation, it is exceptionally impractical, extremely expensive, and otherwise unnecessary for things like machine learning. As DenisM states, you can run TF off-chain and reference its results with Oraclize, but you will not be able to run long-running or computationally intensive TF tasks using the micro instance.

Comment: As a quick addendum to this, Oraclize plans to introduce long-running instances. Some other alternatives also may include projects such as Golem/TrueBit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Oraclize's computation datasource to do something with TF libraries, from within a docker container, running on an AWS micro instance. The instance can only run up to a max of ~10 minutes (assume 7 or 8 as spin-up is a part of this timer), so account for that if you decide to use it, you can read more on it at the official Oraclize documentation: https://docs.oraclize.it/#data-sources-computation

Any sort of machine-learning computations etc... are highly unlikely to take part on the EVM, as per Vitalik's own words, it's 1 million times more expensive than current mainstream computing, so makes very little sense in machine learning sense, except maybe to share/distribute models, or crowdsource training in some form and making the trained model available on-chain. The computation DS could be used for such an AI crowdsourced training initiative.

Comment: Thanks! Certainly agree that it is not viable to use EVM to perform ML tasks. The original idea I had in mind was to initially to making smart contracts smarter through the use of ML without updating the EVM state machine. i.e., kind of of a getter method.